# Amazon Ec2 node server Linux

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-ec2

One of my client has node server installed on Ec2 instance. I am able to access the files and edit them. However changes are not reflecting. I guess I need to restart the server.

However I am not able to do so. Terminal is showing "Command not found" when using both "node" and "nodejs" (Even with sudo).

I am new to both AWS and Angular. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What command you are using to restart?

Comment: yes you need to restart the node server to make changes visible. Are you using beanstalk or a regular ec2 instance? Does /usr/bin/node work? What does `locate node | grep bin` say?

Comment: I am using beanstalk. Running 'locate node | grep bin' return locate command not found

Comment: Okay. I got this. I was able to restart the application server from Beanstalk dashboard. However I couldn't found a way via SSH.